# Referring to a separate file for connection strings for appsettings.json?

Tags: json, asp.net-core

In my .net framework projects I like to have the following in my app.config

```
 <connectionStrings configSource="connections.config" />
```

with connections.config containing something like

```
 <connectionStrings>

   <add name="ApplicationDatabase" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=mydatabase;User Id=myuser; PWD=mypassword;"  />

</connectionStrings>
```

Then I don't check connections.config into source code.

I want to use a similar trick with .NET Core, but it makes use of appsettings.json

via

```
     services.AddDbContext<ApiDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase")));
```

How do I proceed?

Comment: move it to another json file and load it along with the other settings file when needed. Docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#file-configuration-provider

Comment: that is the answer, care to write it up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a separate JSON file (or XML, or any of the configuration providers) and load that at application startup:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddJsonFile("connectionstrings.json", optional: true);
    })
```

Take a look at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#file-configuration-provider) for all the supported configuration providers.

Answer (score 1):

For those who would encounter similar situation when they want to secure the connection string (or any other sensitive values) can simply use [User Secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows). In Visual Studio (tested on 2019) right clicking on the project, then clicking on "Manage User Secrets" would open `secrets.json` file that is a hidden file. Keys/values can be entered here just like appsettings.json file.